# List <string> to display in Partial MVC 3-Razor View -AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this would be easy for most of you folks, but I am new to this .net stuff.
Trying to pass a list of string List to partial view, which is called with jquery load method

```
$('#tree-res').load("@Url.Action("GetTreeView" , "TreeView" )");
```

and i am calling this view from controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetTreeView()
    {
        List<string> list=new List<string>();
        list.Add("Something");
        return PartialView("TreeView",list);
    }
```

Now, how to iterate over this list and display it in TreeView.cshtml

following throws errors :

```
@model List<string>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
}
```

Thanks

Following is stack trace:

```
Line 1:  @model List<string>
Line 2:  @foreach (var item in Model)
Line 3:  {
Line 4:  }
```

> ```
> Source File: c:\scm\branches\Quest\Views\TreeView\TreeView.cshtml
> ```
>
> Line: 2
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> ```
>
> of an object.]
>       ASP._Page_Views_treeview_TreeView_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\scm\branches\Quest\Views    \TreeView\TreeView.cshtml:2
>       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
>       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
>
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
>       System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
>       System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>       System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) +303
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +23
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
>       ....

Comment: added error please have a look

Comment: Could the list itself have a null string value in that collection?  Although, where the error points seems to suggest definitely the Model is null.... (since it points to line 2, and the variable item can adequately represent a null, so Model is the only thing that can go wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly looks like your Model is null. Have you made sure you've recompiled since adding code in `GetTreeView`?